# Is GDDR5 compatible with DDR3?

Tags: windows, firefox, unix

I want to buy a MSI GeForce GTX 760 that is GDDR5 and I have a motherboard that is only DDR3. The thing is, I don't know if there is a newer type of motherboard that can support GDDR5 or my motherboard is high enough to support that video card.

Comment: Sorry, I'm here because I'm newbie at IT an PC stuff and maybe you are the best on IT or you know more than me but you don't have to mark it as spam...if there was something like 'www.normaluser.com' I would go there. But it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

GDDR is the memory on the graphics card.   What you need to make sure is compatible is the PCIe card slot on your motherboard.   DDR3 is the system memory, which uses a completely different bus than graphics memory.   You do not have to worry about any issues other than if your motherboard has the correct PCIe slot for that card.